# Create new column and fill up row values based on date.time colum

Tags: r, lubridate

I tried to find a solution but could not find one here.
I need to create a new column and label each row values of this new column based on a column which is a "Date.Time" format. This Date.Time column spans several days and I want to label in new column values as Day 1 if the values are between certain date.time values.

```
Day_1_start <- ymd_hms ("2018-07-02 00:00:00"),
Day_1_end <- ymd_hms ("2018-07-03 00:00:00")
Day_2_start <- ymd_hms ("2018-07-04 00:00:00")
Day_2_end <- ymd_hms ("2018-07-05 00:00:00")

interval_1 <- interval (Day_1_start, Day_1_end)
interval_2 <- interval (Day2_start, Day_2_end)
```

If the value in Date.Time column is between interval_1, the corresponding label in new column is Day 1 and so on.

I tried:

```
for (i in 1:file$Date.Time) {
    if (file$Date.Time[i] == %within% interval_1) {
        file$Day <- 1
          }
      }
```

The above mentioned code does not work and is just a representation of a pseudocode. Would R community members help me figure out a solution for this?

Or this is an example, where first column has Date.Time and I want to create second column named Group where all the Date.Time between 13:30 and 13:40 will be labeled 1, between 13:40 and 13:50 will be labeled 2 and so on.

```
Date.Time   Group
5/7/18 13:30    1
5/7/18 13:31    1
5/7/18 13:32    1
5/7/18 13:33    1
5/7/18 13:34    1
5/7/18 13:35    1
5/7/18 13:36    1
5/7/18 13:37    1
5/7/18 13:38    1
5/7/18 13:39    1
5/7/18 13:40    2
5/7/18 13:41    2
5/7/18 13:42    2
5/7/18 13:43    2
5/7/18 13:44    2
5/7/18 13:45    2
5/7/18 13:46    2
5/7/18 13:47    2
5/7/18 13:48    2
5/7/18 13:49    2
5/7/18 13:50    3
5/7/18 13:51    3
5/7/18 13:52    3
5/7/18 13:53    3
5/7/18 13:54    3
5/7/18 13:55    3
5/7/18 13:56    3
5/7/18 13:57    3
5/7/18 13:58    3
5/7/18 13:59    3
```

Thank you.

Comment: can you output `dput(head(file$Date.Time))`

Comment: You almost certainly don't need a for loop, since R uses vector operations for exactly this type of task, but you'll need to post a sample of data for anyone to show you how to do that

Comment: @camille  Thanks for your reply. I have added an example in the question section. Your help is much appreciated.

Comment: @Onyambu  Thanks for your reply. I added an example to clarify my issue. Thanks for your help.